# why windows are duplicated on my screen when I set position of window at runtime ? (LIBGDX)

Tags: libgdx

Problem: Windows are cloned on screen, when set the position of the window.

In my `ApplicationAdapter.create()` I create a Window and add it to the stage:

```
window = new Window("titleWindow", skin);
stage.addActor(window);
```

in the `ApplicationAdapter.render()` I reposition the window as follow:

```
    if(rendercount % 100 == 0){
        window.setPosition(100 + count,300);
    }
rendercount++
```

Why my window is cloned on my screen ? I just wanted to move it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you clearing your screen in the beginnig of the *render*() method?

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.5f, 0.6f);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Comment: Ups. Thank you very much.